# Javascript add div to top of another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add a div element at the top inside another div element.

```
<div class="chat-box" id="chat-box">
    <div class="item">
        <img src="avatar.png"/>
        <p class="message">
        <a href="#" class="name"><small class="text-muted pull-right"><i class="fa fa-clock-o">Date</i></small></a>
        Message
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to add new "item" divs above the ones that are already there.
Is there any jquery or javascript snipped that does this for me?

Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: [.prepend()](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.append()` will append it at the end of `#chat-box`.

`.prepend()` will **pre**-pend it, at the beginning of it, like what you're trying to achive.

```
var new_item_html = "<div class='item'>i am an item</div>"
$("#chat-box").prepend(new_item_html);
```

hope that helps.

Comment: Works like a charm! Didn't know it was that easy. Thanks a lot!

Comment: it doesn't seems to add HTML, just plain text "<div class='item'>i am an item</div>"

Answer (score 0):

In general the div's display is in their order. Any additional div will be the last on top.
Use in the div's style position:absolute